# Oracle subtract 5 business working days from SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, select

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO ln_count
    FROM batches eb
    JOIN template_groups ebtg
      ON ebtg.ebtg_id = eb.ebtg_id
   WHERE ebtg.group_name = upper(pvi_batch_group_name)
     AND eb.created_ts > SYSDATE - 5
     AND eb.status = 'COMPLETE';
```

Above query only subtracts 5 days including weekends, but not sure how to exlcude Sat and Sun.

Comment: What about public holidays? Do you have to consider them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just one specific scenario of 5 business days, then 5 business days usually translates to 7 calendar days. Perhaps you could use 7 instead of 5, provided your create date does not fall on a weekend:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO ln_count
    FROM batches eb
    JOIN template_groups ebtg
      ON ebtg.ebtg_id = eb.ebtg_id
   WHERE ebtg.group_name = upper(pvi_batch_group_name)
     AND eb.created_ts > SYSDATE - 7
     AND eb.status = 'COMPLETE';
```

Comment: The batches are ran via DBMS scheduler job daily only on Weekdays so yes you're right created date will never fall on a weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
WHERE eb.created_ts > SYSDATE - 7
    AND TO_CHAR(eb.created_ts, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = american') not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
```

Note, this solution does not consider public holidays. If you need to take them into account the solution is more complex.

Comment: What about company holidays?

Comment: @EdStevens, Would be also my question, however according to above comments `created_ts` will never be weekend (or public holidays, I assume)

Comment: may not be _created_ on a holiday, but but the presence of a holiday skews the actual dates of '5 business days'.  So, in the US, most public holidays occur on a Monday.  So if a 'create date' is on the Tuesday immediately after a Monday holiday, that Monday doesn't factor in to '5 business days'.

Answer (score 1):

This is not that easy. I would check the current day of the week and do conditional logic to compute how many days need to be substracted from it:

```
sysdate 
- case to_char(sysdate, 'fmdy') 
    case 'fri' then 5
    case 'sat' then 6
    case 'sun' then 7
    case 'mon' then 7
    case 'tue' then 7
    case 'wed' then 7
    case 'thu' then 6
end
```

This can be factorized a little:

```
sysdate 
- case 
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmdy') = 'fri' then 5
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmdy') in ('sat', 'thu') then 6
    else 7
end
```